# Plotting a stacked table into a barchart - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, stacked-chart

I aggregated my table into the following table using

```
test_df = countData_df
stackedTable =  test_df.reset_index().pivot_table(values='volume', index=['address', 'direction'], 
aggfunc='sum')
```

[image]

noe I want to create a barchart, where has four colours for different directionon the bar. Each bar can be only two options: N or S; E or W

SO I completed the line as

```
test_df.reset_index().pivot_table(values='volume', index=['address', 'direction'], 
aggfunc='sum').plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True,  color = ['b','g','r','m'])
```

but it shows as following

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there with the code. To fix the plot, you need to unstack the direction. In the example, the direction is a part of the index, but it should be some kind of grouping element for volume.

```
test_df.reset_index().pivot_table(values='volume', index=['address', 'direction'], 
aggfunc='sum').unstack("direction").plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True,  color = ['b','g','r','m'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df[['direction', 'volume']]
df = df.groupby('direction').sum()
```